# Unable to delete duplicate MySQL rows

Tags: mysql

I had an issue when copying data from one table to another where the data copied twice, I am trying to remove the duplicate rows but it is not working

I have tried to run this command

```
DELETE t1 
  FROM users t1 
  JOIN users t2  
 WHERE  t1.id > t2.id 
   AND t1.email = t2.email;
```

from the command line but it just freezes even after waiting for about 10 minutes

I have about 14,000 rows that are duplicated so I'm not sure if that could be part of the issue

Comment: It's often quicker to create a new table with just the data you want to retain

Comment: @Strawberry how would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that you have only 14k records you can create a new table with adding a unique constraint validation & migrate the data into the new table.

-- Create a new table

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT a.* 
  FROM old_table a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT MIN(id) id
         FROM old_table
        GROUP
           BY email
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id;
```

-- Add constraint

```
ALTER TABLE new_table ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
ALTER TABLE new_table ADD UNIQUE(email);
```

-- Rename and drop the old table.

```
DROP TABLE old_table;
RENAME TABLE new_table TO old_table;
```